# WPF applacation window screen shot displayed on button

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010

i have create a few WPF applications in visual studio, and now i would like to create a final application to run all of the created apps in the final application. i would like to know how i can create a layout that displays the apps that are running inside the final app as  buttons that can be clicked and cause the app to expand and allow the user to work on that app and then when finished return back to the final app and see the other apps to choose from. I imagine it would look like a Google chrome blank page that allows you see your familiar webpages and click on them to load them up. Any help or advice on what i should focus on to implement this would be much appreciated.

Thank you for taking the time to read over this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using a VisualBrush this takes other WPF UI (your "apps") and uses their UI as a brush for another UI element.

[Raj Kumar](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/authors/raj1979/raj-kumar.aspx) has a simple article called [Visual Brush in WPF](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/raj1979/visual-brush-in-wpf/) for details.

The bit you probably want is at the bottom where he shows you rendering a controls content in another control. The magic being binding the controls visual to the element name whos UI it should render.